# How can I enable tinyMCE in Umbraco to add a div with a class attribute and contain a paragraph?

Tags: tinymce, umbraco

I need to allow add a div with a class attribute in  tinyMCE in Umbraco. I can add a div, but all content in the div is just text. I need that text has a paragraph, and finally add a class attribute for the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<div class="section'></div>');
```

This will insert the specified html into the editor at the local caret position.
Be aware that your [valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements) and [valid_children](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_children) configuration settings won't strip out anything from the html that you insert.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to understand what you are asking, but I think this should help.

http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/recommendations/recommended-reading-for-content-editors/adding-styles-to-the-tinymce

You can basically associate a stylesheet with the tinyMCE and then add styles to it that will appear in the style dropdown

Comment: Thanks, sorry for my English, why i want to do is , insert a div with a class  attribute named 'section'

Comment: you want tinyMCE to insert a div with the class of section?

Comment: A class, insert a div with a class

Answer (score 0):

If you can paste your template code then we can be more of a help to you.

What you want to do is wrap your `<umbraco:Item field="aliasOfYourRTE" runat="server" />`

with the div you want so in your case your code will look like this:

```
<div class="YOURCLASSNAMEHERE">
  <umbraco:Item field="bodyText" runat="server" />
</div>
```

The umbraco RTE automatically spits out `<p> </p>` tags when content is inserted. Also, make sure you are publishing your node so that your content is viewable on the front end.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, i need do this ,via TinyMce  ( <div id="pdinfo"> <div class="section'></div> <div class="section"></div>....</div>), insert many div with class attribute on a div that is on the template like the body

Comment: Oh so you want to be able to insert divs through the RTE? ( TinyMCE = RTE "Rich Text Editor" ). That I have never seen before - maybe try posting on the umbraco forum? http://our.umbraco.org/

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings - Styles.
Open the stylesheet with the styles for the Format dropdown of TinyMCE in Data Type Richtexteditor.
Add a style with the Alias div.class, e.g. div.alert alert-danger.
If you then click in TinyMCE on a paragraph and then choose in the Format dropdown this style the paragraph is formatted as follows:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger"> ... </div>
```

Is this what you wished to do?